# Python - open a website and send cookies

Tags: python, cookies, session-cookies, python-webbrowser, python-3.7

How to send a cookie to the webbrowser using Python (I am using version 3.7)?

I know how to open a website:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://www.example.com", new=2)
```

But I have no idea, how to open that site with some cookies saved somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you need to send a GET or POST request obj and put those cookies in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Now, I am looking into selenium webdriver. I hope it will give me a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem using selenium and a webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("http://www.example.com")
browser.add_cookie({
    'name' : 'myLovelyCookie',
    'value' : 'myLovelyValue'
})
```

And the result:
[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upIkn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it using the webbrowser library, but this can be easily done with the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. For example:

```
import requests
cookie = {
    'uid': 'example_user_id', 
}
url = "https://example.com"
req = requests.get(url, cookies=cookie)
```

From there you can read the content of the server’s response, contained in req.

Comment: But how to open browser now?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah not sure how to open it in a browser, this would just get all the info from that URL with the cookies.